# WCF authentication failed in runtime

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I am totally new to WCF and I am stuck in this problem for so long, so please be patient with me :)

I am creating a chatting service and a login service. When I run the code in the debug mode, it runs perfectly but when in the runtime, it doesn't workout!

This is my Service Library .. I created it as WCF service library. It has the following App.config where 192.168.1.72 is my local address.

```
   <services>
  <service name="ServiceLibrary.LoginAndSignup">
    <!--<endpoint address=http://192.168.1.72:60982/WebHost/ServiceLibrary.svc -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              contract="ServiceLibrary.ILoginAndSignup">
      <identity>
        <dns value="192.168.1.72"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.72:8732/LoginAndSignup/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
    <service name="ServiceLibrary.GPH_QuickMessageService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                contract="ServiceLibrary.IMessageServiceInbound">
        <identity>
          <dns value="192.168.1.72"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.72:8732/TextChat/"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
</services>
```

I created a website as a web host and added the services as web service references. This is my Web.Config

```
  <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_LoginAndSignup">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_GPH_QuickMessageService"/>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.72:8732/TextChat/" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_GPH_QuickMessageService" contract="TextChat_Non_Local.GPH_QuickMessageService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_GPH_QuickMessageService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="192.168.1.72"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.72:8732/LoginAndSignup/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_LoginAndSignup" contract="Login_Non_Local.LoginAndSignup" name="BasicHttpBinding_LoginAndSignup"/>
</client>
<services>
  <service name="ServiceLibrary.LoginAndSignup">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ServiceLibrary.ILoginAndSignup">
      <identity>
        <dns value="192.168.1.72"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.72:8732/LoginAndSignup/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
  <service name="ServiceLibrary.GPH_QuickMessageService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="ServiceLibrary.IMessageServiceInbound">
      <identity>
        <dns value="192.168.1.72"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.72:8732/TextChat/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

I am really so sorry for my long post but this is the last thing. I created a client and added the services as a service references. Here is my app.config for the client

```
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_LoginAndSignup" >
            <security mode="None" />
          </binding>

        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_GPH_QuickMessageService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.72:8732/TextChat/" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_GPH_QuickMessageService"
            contract="NewTextChat.GPH_QuickMessageService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_GPH_QuickMessageService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="192.168.1.72" />
            </identity><endpoint address="http://192.168.1.72:8732/LoginAndSignup/"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_LoginAndSignup"
            contract="Login_Non_Local.LoginAndSignup" name="BasicHttpBinding_LoginAndSignup" />
    </client>
        </endpoint>
```

Can anyone help me with that? I want to connect 2 pcs on these services but it is never working out :( and I apologize again for the long post